# How to extract and store in a string array the text between <strong> and <br> that are inside <p> tag having no html code(i.e &nbsp; etc) in it

Tags: java, jsoup

Extract the text from strong and `<br>` tags in paragraph tag as a separate string.
I have tried to split the text with `<br>` regex but the text contains HTML code like `p`, `strong` and `nbsp`.

Example code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
Elements Paragraphs = doc.getElementsByTag("p");
String options = Paragraphs.first().html();
String[] singleOption = options.split("<br>");
```

I want to extract the text from strong and `<br>` tags and store each one in index of an array.

Comment: Is that text only inside `<strong>..</strong>`? In that case having it <br> after it may be irrelevant if you just select that `strong` element and call `text()` on it, something like `Paragraphs.first().select("strong").text()`.

Comment: I need the whole text inside the paragraph, i.e the text inside the <strong> and between the <br> tags.

Comment: Post example of HTML and expected results *as text* so we could copy it and work on it.

Comment: Please replace the *images* of input text and output with plain text (formatted as "code"). See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also confirm there are not multiple occurrences of such structures within the input, or if that's possible what the output should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your split regex to `<br>|</?strong>` this splits a String at `<br>` and `<strong>` tags. To remove other Tags you can use `Jsoup.clean(string, Whitelist.none())`. To unescape unicode characters use `Parser.unescapeEntities(string, false)`.

Combining all that using Java Streams the solution would look like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String[] parts = doc.select("p").stream()
        .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.html().split("<br>|</?strong>")))
        .map(s -> Jsoup.clean(s, Whitelist.none()))
        .map(s -> Parser.unescapeEntities(s, false))
        .map(String::trim)
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

This searches for all paragraphs parses them.

For the example input:

```html
<p>foo b<i>a</i>r <strong>test</strong><br>abc&nbsp;xyz</p>
<p>hi <strong>this&nbsp;is<br>a<br>test</strong></p>
```

The result will be:

```
[foo bar, test, abc xyz, hi, this is, a, test]
```